# nginx serving nested static files

Tags: nginx, flask

So I am trying to server some static files with nginx on an ubuntu server and using flask
here is my file structure:

home/user/app/app/static
and in static I have css, js, images and players.
Here is the nginx code:

```
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name ip;

        location /static {
                root /home/user/app/app/static;
        }

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
                include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
                proxy_redirect off;
        }
}
```

I thought the problem was because of the permissions:

```
 drwxr-xr-x root root /
 drwxr-xr-x root root home
 drwxr-xr-x user user user
 drwx------ user user app
 drwx------ user user app
 drwx------ user user static
```

I tried `sudo chown user:nginx /home/user/app` and it gives the this error chown: invalid group: ‘user:nginx’

I can load the html page and all the flask functionality except for the static.

Comment: Your problem IS permissions and your question is off-topic in StackOverflow. It is better suited to [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) or to [Superuser](https://superuser.com).

Comment: You probably have the wrong value for `root`. Try `root /home/user/app/app;` - see [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root).